# Coset construction of Tricritical Ising CFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, group-theory, conformal-field-theory, lie-algebra

In http://iopscience.iop.org/1742-5468/2008/03/P03010

the authors state that the Tricritical Ising Model (TIM) CFT can be obtained from a Wess Zumino Witten construction based in the coset $\frac{(E_7)_1\otimes(E_7)_1}{(E_7)_2}$, where $(E_7)_k$ is the exceptional Lie algebra $E_7$ at level $k$.

My question is: Is there another coset construction of TIM CFT that does not use an exceptional Lie algebra?

Answer (score 2):

Tricritical Ising model belongs to the family of minimal models ($M(5,4)$). There are several different coset constructions that represent them, one of them is the following:

$M(m+1,m)=SU(2)_{m-2} \times SU(2)_1/SU(2)_{m-1}$